# Use colon as filename separator in zsh tab completion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have programs which take filename arguments as

```
scp:path/to/file.ext
ark:/abs/path/to/file.ext
```

Is it possible make zsh complete filenames after some keywords followed by colon?

So far, I found how to do it in bash: add `:` to the `COMP_WORDBREAKS` variable.

---

Thanks to Gilles, I manage to work like this.

```
$ cat ~/.zshrc
...
function aftercolon() {
  if compset -P 1 '*:'; then
    _files "$expl[@]"
  else
    _files "$expl[@]"
  fi
}

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
compdef aftercolon hello olleh
```

Now in commands `hello` and `olleh`, completion after : works as expected.

I think there might be better way since:

1. I had to odd if/else since the commands also take filename without prefix.
2. And since I have many commands take this kind of argument, I need to add  names of every commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`compset -P 1 '*:'`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compset) to remove everything up to the first colon, then `_files` to complete what comes after the colon. For example, if the file name completions don't depend on the part before the colon:

```
if compset -P 1 '*:'; then
  _files "$expl[@]"
else
  compadd "$expl[@]" -S : ark scp
fi
```

If the file name completions depend on the part before the colon, save that from `$PREFIX` first.

```
if [[ $PREFIX = *:* ]]; then
  local domain=${PREFIX%%:*}
  compset -P 1 '*:'
  case $domain in
    ark) _files "$expl[@]" -g "*.((tar|cpio)(|.gz|.xz|.bz2)|tgz|zip|rar|7z)";;
    *) _files "$expl[@]";;
  esac
else
  compadd "$expl[@]" -S : ark scp
fi
```

Comment: thank you. but I am quiet newbie to zsh completion system. How do you apply this to shell? I added the snippet to .zshrc but failed. I want this completion works for all commands and no need to depend on prefix part.

Comment: @auditory This is very different from your original question. Please ask a new question. Ask on [unix.se], because your new question is off-topic here: it's about user configuration, not about programming.